# AJAX returning data PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, ajax

I have an insert function on my page that uses AJAX/PHP to insert data into myMySQL table, When a row of data is added, my row of data is returned and printed out inside...

```
 <div id="bills"></div>
```

I can then add another row of data, When i do this however it overwrites the contents of #bills, is there a way to add it to the information in there as opposed to overwriting that?

***AJAX***

```
function insertBill()
{
    $.post('insert_bill.php', $('form').serialize(), 
        function(data) {***
        $("#bills").html(data); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#bills').append(data);
```

[jQuery.fn.append documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
$("#bills").append(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.html()` use `.append()`

```
$("#bills").append(data);
```

`data` can contain html tags and jQuery will do the right thing.